# What is Apache Ambari Enterprise Price per hour?

Tags: ambari

As ambari comes under cloudera now, what is the price per hour of the enterprise edition of apache ambari

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score -1):

@asukwal9 -  Ambari is no longer a part of Cloudera enterprise support and there was never a per hour consumption for Ambari or HDP (Hortonworks Data Platform).   Enterprise licensing was node based not consumption based.  Today enterprise level support for these services around Ambari is End of Life unless there is an exception.  Existing licensed HDP customers are migrating to CDP (Cloudera Data Platform).